# Pass textbox value on parent form to child form

Tags: c#, winforms, parent-child

I have a winforms application where i have one main form in which i have a panel that i use to display the application's other forms. For example...  Form1 is the main form.  On Form1 there is a panel called "childFormPanel" and 3 buttons to load either Form2, Form3, or Form4 into the panel.  When you click any of these buttons, whatever form is currently loaded in the childFormPanel is hidden and that form is then loaded into the Panel.

Currently, each of the child forms have their own search textbox that a user can enter text into and search a datagrid that the child form holds.  What i would like to do instead, is have just one search textbox that lives on the main form that can pass the text to whatever form is currently loaded into it's panel.

I am not loading the forms using ShowDialog for various reasons and i'm not closing them out and creating a new instance of the form every time but instead hiding/showing them.  Not sure that's relevant but thought i'd include it.  I've gotten the hang of passing data from a child form to a parent, but not necessarily the other way around.

What is the best way to go about having one textbox on a main form that can pass data to whatever child form is loaded?

Any tips/ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Forms are just classes.  Add a method to accept the value/contents and use that method from the other form.

Comment: The easiest way IMO is to use delegates/events

Comment: Why don't you have 3 panels and one form? change the visibility of the panels depending on which button is pressed. You can set the location of the visible panel to the same location so it appears to the user the controls are the only things changing

Comment: Are you aware that Microsoft already invented this wheel for you? Google MDI

Answer (score 0):

I personally use `EventHandler` with a custom `EventArgs` class to send the arbitrary information (in your case the string stored in the `TextBox`).

Here is how to do it.

```
//Custom EventArgs class (that stores a string)
public class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs {
    private string storedValue;

    public string StoredValue {
        get { return storedValue; }
        set { storedValue = value; } 
    }
    
    public CustomEventArgs() {
       storedValue = "";
    }
}
```

```
//Your parent form class
public partial class MainForm : Form {
   //Create the EventHandler containing the custom EventArgs
   public EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> textBoxValueChanged; 
   //Create a CustomEventArgs variable to avoid needing an new instance of it every time it is needed
   private CustomEventArgs textChangedArgs; 
   
   
   public MainForm() {
      textChangedArgs = new CustomEventArgs();
   }

   //Assuming you want the TextChanged event for your TextBox but can be whatever
   protected void searchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      textChangedArgs.StoredValue = searchTextBox.Text;
      CustomEventArgs(sender, textChangedArgs);
   }

   private void loadChildForm() { //The method where your childforms are created
      ChildForm cForm = new ChildForm();
      CustomEventArgs += cForm.searchInForm; //Here you "subscribe" the eventhandler to the searchInForm method in the child form
      cForm.ShowDialog();
   }
}
```

```
//The child form class
public partial Class ChildForm : Form {
    
    public void searchInForm(object sender, CustomEventArgs args) {
        string searchValue = args.StoredValue; //Text current text in SearchTextBox in MainForm
    }
}
```

Now every time the users changes the text in your main text box (I called it `searchTextBox`) the `EventHandler` `textBoxValueChanged` is triggered which calls all of its subscribed method (i.e. the `searchInForm` method `ChildForm`). There you can now get the stored string in the custom `EventArgs`, which is the text in your `TextBox`, and do the logic that is needed for searching.

You can subscribe to all of the child forms in the `loadChildForm` method in `MainForm` but you have to have the `searchInForm` method in every child form.

Please note that you can add more variables in `CustomEventArgs` if you want to pass more information to the child form class.

Comment: This is odd; the thing that raises the event is the form but the thing that is declared to be the sender is the textbox. Also feels like this code could be reduced a lot and the essential point be more clear as a result..

Comment: Yes you are correct, the sender is the `TextBox` and therefore the custom `EventArgs` might be overkill for just sending a single string and we could use the sender and a regular `EventArgs` to get the `TextBox` text value. However the benefit with using a custom made `EventArgs` is that is very easy to add more variables in the case that more information needs to be sent from the parent form down to the child forms. 

How can the code be reduced "a lot"? We are talking about barely 30 lines of code, including the brackets and class statements. Without the custom `EventArgs` it is even less.

Comment: eg `class CustomEventArgs{ public string StoredValue { get; set; } }` - I can't see the point of assigning  empty string but you can put `set; } = ""; }`

Comment: Also, consider `event` keyword, and don't invoke the handler if it's null..

Answer (score 0):

I seems like each button that loads a form should also set a variable declaring which form is loaded. If all those forms descended from a common parent or implemented the same interface they would all have their own implementation of a search method that the parent would call

```
interface ISearchable{
  public void Search(string term);
}

class AddressForm: ISearchable{
  public void Search(string term){
    bindingsourceX.Filter = $"Name = '{term}'";
  }
}

class PersonForm: ISearchable{
  public void Search(string term){
    using var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Person WHERE firstname = @x", "...");
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@x", term);
    var dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    persondatagridview.DataSource = dt;
  }
}

class MainForm{

    ISearchable _whichFormIsShowing;

  void ShowPersonFormButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    var f = new PersonForm();
    f.Show(); //or whatever you do

    _whichFormIsShowing = f;
  }

  void ShowAddressFormButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    var f = new AddressForm();
    f.Show(); //or whatever you do

    _whichFormIsShowing = f;
  }

  void PerformSearchOnActiveFormButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    
    _whichFormIsShowing.Search(_termTextbox.Text));
  }

}
```

Take a moment to study the above; I have two forms that are ISearchable which is a fulfilled promise to the compiler that they have a Search method. This means that a variable of type ISearchable can be declared and the compiler will know it can have Search called no matter whether it's a person form or an address form, and each form does its search in a completely different way. Whatever form is showing now will have it's Search called.

Final point, and it's really important. Please, please name your variables and classes better than "Form1", "Form2", "Button1", "Textbox4" etc

You can clearly see exactly what is going on in my code because the naming is clear and obvious. If I'd made it all bland ControlN style names it would be significantly harder to decipher what it does. Be kind to your future self and to people on the internet whose help you will seek, and name your variables well.

Comment: Oh don't be alarmed, i do not actually name any of my variables/controls like in the description of the question, i just did that for ease of explanation for an example.

I would like to try this method here, as i am unfamiliar with using an interface in C! When i attempt to add one though it informs me that i must update my code to C# 8.0.   Will this hurt anything to do this in a mostly already coded projected??

Thank you by the way!

Comment: The c# 8 part is nothing to do with interfaces (which have been a thing since the start), it's probably in relation to my use of the fairly recent `using var x ...` syntax - a way of performing a `using` that doesn't have `{ }` braces. Variable `x` is in scope to the end of the block it is `using var`'d in. That error will go away if you delete or comment out my example code inside the methods